# string split in LINQ

Tags: regex, string, linq, replace, split

This is wat i tried using split

```
string[] req_info_texts = Regex.Matches(model_file_string_qts_corrected, 
                                          "RequirementInfo.*\"")
                               .OfType<Match>()
                               .Select(m=> m.Groups[0].Value.Split('\'').ToString())
                               .ToArray();
```

`RequirementInfo.*\"` Lines in the string `"model_file_string_qts_corrected"` is similar to

```
RequirementInfo   "{'1' 2' 3'4 '5' 6'7' 8'syed_syed' 'SRDD_PFC_047602' } %GIDa_033022bd_8058_4216_8b9d_71454ba5f896"
```

There were n no of lines like above in the string .

I need syed_syed in the array req_info_texts .
But wat i get is index out of range exception.

Can u say wat the mistake is?

Comment: `m.Groups[0].Value.Split('\'').ToString()`, so string[].ToString, does that make sense ?

Comment: i am new to c sharp .correct the above lines of code if they were wrong . i need the output expected

Comment: @user2799127 where would `syed_syed` be..would it be in the 8th `'`??

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is `model_file_string_qts_corrected` a string containing `RequirementInfo   "{'1' 2' 3'4 '5' 6'7' 8'syed_syed' 'SRDD_PFC_047602' } %GIDa_033022bd_8058_4216_8b9d_71454ba5f896"`? Or is it a multiline string? How do you get `syed_syed`? Is it always the 9th item seperated by `'`?

Comment: Take the below one .This is clear model example                RequirementInfo   "{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'RLBL_FSB_BOOLEAN_SWITCHING_1_GRP001' 'SRDD_PFC_047602' } %GIDa_ed66dae7_2d68_4d07_9c67_a1cf1cb614cc"

Comment: In this case it is always the 9th element

Comment: @user2799127 and in other cases?

Comment: Briefly i have a string array with requirementinfo...... in each element of the array. I need a new array with only the 9th element as mentioned above

Comment: At all the cases ,it is 9th element only. @ kexel It is a sinle line string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] req_info_texts = Regex.Matches(input,@"RequirementInfo.*\"")
                               .Cast<Match>()
                               .Select(m=> m.Value
                                            .Split(''')
                                            .Where(x=>x.Contains("syed_syed")) 
                                            .Single()
                                      ).ToArray();
```

Comment: This still is giving index out of range exception

Comment: @user2799127 Show us the exact content of `model_file_string_qts_corrected` in question

Comment: RequirementInfo   "{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP001' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_ed66dae7_2d68_4d07_9c67_a1cf1cb614cc"
  RequirementInfo   "{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP001' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_b9a766f9_2b2b_4ca8_98f4_f693055b4792"
  RequirementInfo   "{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP004' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_271d5326_cb57_4d87_8cd9_66687c0a1d32"
  RequirementInfo   "{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP03' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_07ed6119_91d2_41f9_94dc_69d518503d64"

Comment: Each requirementinfo starts in a new line

Comment: @user2799127 hope it works now..edited the ans..This would take element from the array that contains `syed_syed`

Answer (score 0):

Given your input string is

> RequirementInfo    "{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP001' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_ed66dae7_2d68_4d07_9c67_a1cf1cb614cc" RequirementInfo     "{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP001' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_b9a766f9_2b2b_4ca8_98f4_f693055b4792" RequirementInfo     "{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP004' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_271d5326_cb57_4d87_8cd9_66687c0a1d32" RequirementInfo     "{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP03' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_07ed6119_91d2_41f9_94dc_69d518503d64"

just with newlines, as you said in a comment on another question, you just need two splits:

```
var infosString = "RequirementInfo   \"{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP001' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_ed66dae7_2d68_4d07_9c67_a1cf1cb614cc\"\nRequirementInfo  \"{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP001' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_b9a766f9_2b2b_4ca8_98f4_f693055b4792\"\n RequirementInfo     \"{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP004' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_271d5326_cb57_4d87_8cd9_66687c0a1d32\"\n RequirementInfo     \"{'other' ' ' '' 'true' 'syed_syed_GRP03' 'klajdskfjadklsjfklsa' } %GIDa_07ed6119_91d2_41f9_94dc_69d518503d64";
var result = infosString.Split('\n').Select(line => line.Split('\'')[9]).ToArray();
```

result is now

[image]

The first `Split` creates an array with the strings starting with `RequirementInfo`, and the `Select` splits these strings again and takes the 10th items (the ones starting with `syed_syed`).